# Ember properties with multiple dependencies dont update as expected

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have following issue concerning understanding ember properties:

If i have a propertyA:

```
propertyA: function() {
  return this.get("propertyB.someObject.someValue");
}.property("propertyB")
```

and a propertyB:

```
propertyB: function() {
  return this.get("propertyX.someObject");
}.property("propertyX", "propertyY", "propertyZ")
```

And i have a binding for propertyA in some template like:

```
{{propertyA}}
```

Then in 90% of the cases in my code it happens that **propertyA** does not get updated properly when i **set** i.e. **propertyX**.

If i understand it correctly, then **propertyB** should become **dirty** as soon as one of the dependent properties (like **propertyX**) changes. This should automatically make **propertyA** **dirty** and thus update it automatically since it has a binding.

What happens in my code is, that **propertyA** remains the old cached value even when i called it in the console, but when i call **propertyB** it revaluates and returns the updated code, since it was dirty.

The question is, why does **propertyA** not automatically become dirty when **propertyB** does? Is it because **propertyB** has no binding in a template? I thought it is not necessary if **propertyA** has the dependence.

I also figured out that this problem does not occur when **propertyB** just depends on **propertyX**, so the multi-dependency must somehow mess things up.

Sorry for this quite complicated explanation but i tried to abstract my actual code as simple as possible.

**UPDATE:**

Ok here some actual code:

Controller:

```
styling: function() {
  var clipValues = this.get("clip.styling") || {};
  var infoValues = this.get("clip.info.styling") || {};
  return Ember.Object.create(jQuery.extend({}, clipValues, infos));
}.property("clip.styling", "clip.info.styling"),


showBottombar: function() {
  return (!!this.get("bottombarSrc") || !!this.get("styling.bottombar.fancyStuff"));
}.property("styling"),
```

Somewhere else the clip gets set for this controller. And later its info gets updated in the clip model which is a simple Ember.Object:

```
getInfo: function(url) {
  var self = this;
  return App.ajax(url).then(function(response) {
    self.set("info", response);
  });
}
```

Now after getInfo gets called, the {{showBottombar}} in the template shows "false" even if "bottombarSrc" and "...fancyStuff" is true. When i call "styling" from the console, it reevaluates the styling code which indicates that it was marked as dirty after clip.getInfo happened (which sets the "info"). But this does not effect the showBottombar. It just does not get called afterwards.

**UPDATE 2**

There are two strange ways of making it work, but i dont understand why:

First one is adding a styling binding to a template:

```
{{styling}}
```

That causes showBottombar to get called after the styling changes.

Second one is removing other dependencies from the styling property:

```
styling: function() {
  var clipValues = this.get("clip.styling") || {};
  var infoValues = this.get("clip.info.styling") || {};
  return Ember.Object.create(jQuery.extend({}, clipValues, infos));
}.property("clip.info.styling"),
```

(no more "clip.styling" dependency). Which also causes the showBottombar property to work properly. Both ways work individually.

Comment: can you reproduce in a jsbin?

Comment: Sadly not; so far. I think it is a time-critical issue which happens when two properties like **propertyX** and **propertyY** get dirty at similar times. I'll try to find a way to reproduce it, but is the assumption correct that **propertyA** should be **dirty** for sure, since it dependency (propertyB) changed even though **propertyB** itself has no binding apart from the dependency?

Comment: What are the other two properties? computed properties?  primitive types?  You are saying you depend on propertyB, but truly you depend on propertyB.someObject.someValue likewise propertyY, but then you truly depend on propertyY.someObject.

Comment: Ok the other once are: property X is a property of an Ember.Object which is set on the surrounding content in this case a controller.  And propertyY is another property of that same object. Both are not set on init.

Comment: This jsbin is a bit closer to my actual code although in the example the properties are working as expected: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qewobaseso/edit

Comment: `propertyB` will be recalculated when `propertyX` is changed, but will return the same value, since `propertyX` is not involved in the caculation. Since the value did not change it will not trigger the recomputation of `propertyA`--why should it?

Comment: That i also thought until i had a problem where properties got called even though dependencies did not change. I opened a ember issue: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/10510 where someone explained that the properties dont check the return value for changes but mark any depending properties as dirty if a dependent one changes (for performance reasons). Also in my case "propertyB" changes (i made an mistake in the code. The return value should be "propertyX.someObject" instead of "propertyY.someObject".

Answer (score 0):

```
 propertyA: function() {
   return this.get("propertyB.someObject.someValue");
 }.property("propertyB").volatile()
```

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ComputedProperty.html#method_volatile

Comment: Tried **volatile** before without success. Even then **propertyA** does not get called when **propertyB** becomes dirty.

Comment: Did you make propertyB volatile as well? Basically, make any property which depends on other properties volatile.

Comment: I did. Same effect. There is no problem with propertyB caching because when i call it via console, i can see that it reevaluates the function even without using "volatile". The problem is, that propertyA does not recognise its dirty state.

Comment: Can you show all the relevant code? Actual code, not _propertyB.someObject.someValue_.